# mat-slider not listening to getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an angular project where i got additional javascript loaded included in the angular.json file under de scripts section. in this js file are a bunch of event listeners in particular this one:

```
document.getElementById("volume").addEventListener("input", volChangeFunc, false)
```

The problem i am having is that i'm using mat-slider like this:

```
<mat-slider id="volume" thumbLabel color="primary"></mat-slider>
```

and it seems that the js doesn't detect the mat-slider element with document.getElementById("volume"). If i use the classic input type="range" everything works fine.

How can i make it so mat-slider also works? I hope someone can help me with this issue.
(PS: i also tried binding the mat-slider to a hidden input range field but i ran into issues with triggering the event this way as well. but definitely a usable option if needed)

Comment: I think the id only works on native elements, the mat slider is an angular component. the id gets omitted when it gets printed on the dom

Comment: @FaizalHussain when i add an id on mat-slider and inspect element i can see it

Comment: you might be trying to access the element before it gets compiled?

Comment: You don’t really need this at all.. mat-slider already has a (input) and a (change) emitter you can use.

Comment: @MikeOne i tried to explain that i need it because the logic (which is a huge part of the app) is being done in that javascript. so the conventional input change emitters from angular won't work

Comment: @FaizalHussain but then why would it work if i use the old input element with type="range"?

Comment: because it loads faster than the angular slider component , you have to load the script after the entire app has been loaded , try running the script with lifecycle hooks

Comment: Do you have control over those external scripts?

Comment: @MikeOne yes but it's not really feasable to change the entire logic of it since its huge. but i can make changes to it.

Comment: Right. Because it’s external, you have no way to detect when angular is ready building that slider plus, i doubt the element itself actually emits the event globally like that anyways. The only option I see is to use the build in event emitters and have a handler in the component that emits a custom event on document or window. Then change your external script to listen to those events. That way you’re not depending on load order or existence of dom elements.

Comment: cant you attach the script dynamically , after angular is loaded ? ?

Comment: @FaizalHussain actually i would prefer it that way but i can't find how to do it. do you have any reference i can use to do that?

Comment: Problem is, you don’t really know when ‘angular is loaded’ - let alone when the view of a subcomponent is ready. Even then, I doubt the input event on the outer mat-slider is triggered in a way you can catch it with a normal event listener..

Comment: @MikeOne do you have any information i can use to make a custom event emitter? i made it so i can catch the value in the component now with the (input) emitter but i don't know how to make a custom event emitter for my external js to listen to like you suggested

Comment: Sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events, just make sure you use a high level dom element to dispatch and listen on like document…

Comment: @MikeOne i use this inside the component?

Comment: Yes. So you create the custom event with payload (the value of the volume slider?) in the component and then dispatch that event on document.

Comment: you can use something like this 
ngAfterViewInit() {
const node = document.createElement('script');
      node.src =  'path to your script';
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      node.async = false;
      node.charset = 'utf-8';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);


 }

Comment: And in your script you add an event listener (also on document) that catches those events. You can name the event to whatever seems to make sense.

Comment: @MikeOne ok i figured it out and its working good. thanks you so much :) i just would like to know if Faizal Hussain 's method would work as well? because the scripts are being imported at startup it actually produces an error on the homepage. so having it only load in when a specific component is loaded would be preferable. Would doing that also solve the issue i had?

Comment: You can definitely try, but I doubt if it will fix your issue.